# React Hook on the project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but what it is your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is no valid question.

Answer (score -2):

In class components you cannot use "useState".
You need to use states and "setState" in class components.